# Android rotate map but leave polygon at same screen position

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I have a map onto which I draw a polygon. After I draw the initial polygon, I rotate the map in a circle, 1 degree at a time, doing a full circle in about 5 seconds.

The thing is that I would like the polygon to stay in the same position on the screen, not on the map. If I do nothing with the polygon while rotating the map, the polygon rotates as well. This is not the desired behaviour, I would like the polygon to stay in the same place on the screen while the map is rotated.

I have tried using the following methods to get the new poly-points but it is not coming out properly. I have been using a bearing of 0 and 135 as my tests and the results are displayed below.

**Methods:**

```
//degrees = counter-clockwise from north
private List<LatLng> getPolygonPoints(LatLng startPoint, int bearing) {
    LatLng firstPoint = getPolyPoint(startPoint, 100, getPolyPointDifference(90, bearing));
    LatLng fourthPoint = getPolyPoint(startPoint, 100, getPolyPointDifference(270, bearing));

    LatLng secondPoint = getPolyPoint(firstPoint, 300, getPolyPointDifference(10, bearing));
    LatLng thirdPoint = getPolyPoint(fourthPoint, 300, getPolyPointDifference(350, bearing));

    return Arrays.asList(
        startPoint,
        firstPoint,
        secondPoint,
        thirdPoint,
        fourthPoint,
        startPoint
    );
}

private int getPolyPointDifference(int fromNorth, int bearing) {
    int[] compass = new int[360];
    int currentBearing = 360 - bearing;

    if (currentBearing == 360) {
        currentBearing = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        compass[i] = currentBearing;
        currentBearing++;

        if (currentBearing >= 360) {
            currentBearing = 0;
        }
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "fromNorth: "+fromNorth+" return: "+compass[fromNorth]);

    return compass[fromNorth];
}

//distance = meters
//degrees = counter-clockwise from north
private LatLng getPolyPoint(LatLng fromLocation, int distance, int degrees) {
    double radians = (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;

    double distanceX = distance * Math.sin(radians);
    double distanceY = distance * Math.cos(radians);

    double deltaLatitude = distanceY / 110540;
    double deltaLongitude = distanceX / (111320 * Math.cos(fromLocation.latitude));

    double pointLatitude = fromLocation.latitude + deltaLatitude;
    double pointLongitude = fromLocation.longitude + deltaLongitude;

    return new LatLng(pointLatitude, pointLongitude);
}
```

**Output:**

Bearing = 0

- fromNorth: 90 return: 90
- fromNorth: 270 return: 270
- fromNorth: 10 return: 10
- fromNorth: 350 return: 350

Bearing = 135

- fromNorth: 90 return: 315
- fromNorth: 270 return: 135
- fromNorth: 10 return: 235
- fromNorth: 350 return: 215

**Result:**

[Bearing 0](http://tinypic.com/r/e1axow/8)

[Bearing 135](http://tinypic.com/r/2mys32b/8)

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that I would like the polygon to stay in the same position on the screen, not on the map.

Then do not draw it on the map but on i.e. overlay surface you create.

Comment: The thing is that I am only displaying map markers that fall within this polygon so the polygon itself has to be part of the map to know what coordinates it falls on in the map